# Do I have to call memset after I allocated new memory using malloc

Tags: c, malloc, memset

```
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int *test = malloc(15 * sizeof(int));
    for(int i = 0;i < 15 ;i  ++ )
        printf("test is %i\n",test[i]);

    memset(test,0,sizeof(int) * 15);

    for(int i = 0 ; i < 15; i ++ )
        printf("test after memset is %i\n",test[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

The output I get is very weird:

```
    test is 1142126264
    test is 32526
    ...
    test is 1701409394
    test is 1869348978
    test is 1694498930
    test after memset is 0
    test after memset is 0
    test after memset is 0
    test after memset is 0
    test after memset is 0
    ...
    test after memset is 0
    test after memset is 0
    test after memset is 0
    test after memset is 0
    test after memset is 0
```

Why would that happen?
I thought I just `malloc`ed some new fresh memory that is ready to use?

So how about this:

```
int test[15];
```

Do I have to call
`memset(&test,0,sizeof(int) * 15);` ?

Comment: Initializing every bit of memory would slow down programs that don't need it. I think `calloc` would serve if you need it zeroed.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`malloc` does not initialize the memory it allocates.  You just get whatever random garbage was already in there.  If you really need everything set to 0, use `calloc` at a performance penalty.  (If you need to initialize to something other than 0, use `memset` for byte arrays and otherwise manually loop over the array to initialize it.)

Comment: Why would malloc+memset be any faster than calloc?

Comment: It's likely not faster, but you can initialize to any value, not just zero.

Comment: @1'' that is true only for byte arrays. you shouldn't use malloc to initialize, say, an array of `int`s to anything else than 0

Comment: @CiprianTomoiagă well technically it wouldn't be a problem to malloc() garbage anyway if you're immediately going to fill that array.

Answer (score 2):

C11 7.22.3.4

```
void *malloc(size_t size);
```

> The malloc function allocates space for an object whose **size** is
>   specified by size and whose value is indeterminate.

If you want the values to be set to zero, use `calloc` instead. `calloc` is basically just a wrapper function around one call to `malloc` and one call to `memset` (with value to set is 0).

Answer (score 1):

When you request for a memory from heap, heap will just allocate any block of memory available to it. This block of memory may have some data depending upon a previous write.

Answer (score 0):

For performance reasons, malloc() makes no guarantee regarding the contents of newly allocated memory.  It might be zeros, it might be random data, it might be anything.  If you want malloc'ed memory to have a specific value, then it is up to you do it.