# How to cache part of the data in buffer/ array and have everything else stored in members of data structure in C

Tags: c, arrays, arraylist, data-structures, memcached

I have my pseudocode something like this in C. I have some part of data stored in data structure, but im struggling to have another set of data (based on an if condition) to store in a separate array which is not fixed size. Any suggestion is appreciated.

```
typedef struct struct1 {
    uint32 member1
} PACKED struct1_t

typedef struct struct2 {
    struct1_t *member2
} PACKED struct2_t


uint32 curnt_cnt = 0;
for (i=0; i<some_number; i++){
    if (cond) {
        k = m;
        struct2_t->member2[curnt_cnt].member1 = k; #I have no prob writing here
    }
    else {
        k = n;
        array[curnt_cnt] = k;     ==> Is this even correct implementation?
        # I want to store/ book-keep the values of k in an array throughout every iteration of for loop without overwriting the previous value
        # Size of the array will not exceed "some_number (mentioned in for loop)" at any time     
    }
    curnt_cnt++;
}
```

Comment: Sorry. I don't get what you are trying to do. Please elaborate. Explain more, give examples, show how you intend to use this. Maybe explain about the reasons for you trying this. Please [edit] your question to do so. I recommend to write much prose to talk about your goals. In case you have ever seen something similar show or link that, too.

Comment: Hi @Yunnosch .. The purpose is in the else block, the value of n is stored in k, then I want to store that data in an array for each iteration of for loop. Am I clear?

Comment: @Yunnosch ..I have edited the question as well.

Comment: Hmm, I still do not understand your goal. But lets assume that is just me. Maybe explain about the problem you have with doing this. What keeps you?

Answer (score 2):

You must create a pointer, since lists in C must have a specific size

```c
int* arr;
arr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*some_number);
```

and then in your code

```c
else {
        k = n;
        array[curnt_cnt] = k;
    }
```

will work.

Comment: Cool. This works. Do i have to do memset as well after malloc?

Comment: Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410550/do-i-have-to-call-memset-after-i-allocated-new-memory-using-malloc). And, please, mark the answer as accepted if it solves your problem